# Android map draw circle radio with GPS coordinates from SQLite Database

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, sqlite, gps

Actually I'm developing an application for research with Android by my own and I'd like to develop an application with these features:

The idea is simple:

We have some GPS coordinates stored in the SQLite Database. Using the GPS location manager I'd like to locate my actual location and draw a position pushpin in the map. Once the application locates the current position, I'd like to check the nearest GPS position coordinates from the SQLite database in a radio of, let's say, 10km (may vary).

I have develop some applications: ReadfromSQLiteDB, GetGPSition and the only thing I need is to draw the GPS points within the circle that I'm not pretty sure how to make it.

I'm kindly asking for some advice or help :) Thanks in advance

Here is an example or idea of what I want to make.[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to find the points within the circle, how to draw the circle, how to add the points to and overlay or ... ?

Comment: 1- Find my Location
2- Draw a position arrow like in the previous image using current GPS data
3- Draw a circle with different radio size
4- Get the nearest GPS positions from my current position (GPS position in SQLite)
5- Draw these positions in the map

That's what I'm trying to do :)

Comment: So you want to know how to do each of these things in detail?

Comment: Actually I was trying to find some advice, most of all these features I know how to make it but I havesome problems with the circle and putting the GPS coordenates from my actual location in a radio of 10km. Should I grab the GPS coordenates using a SQL code or Grab all the GPS position to an arrayadapter an once then use a function to check which one are near my position depending on my radio range?

Comment: I think this is too broad a series of questions and you would have better luck posing individual questions, like: Given a large set of coordinates what would be the best method of selecting those that are within a 10KM radius of a center coordinate. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want using [map overlays](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay.html).

- For the user location use [MyLocationOverlay](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html)
- To draw the objects near the user, retrieve the objects from the db (you can ask the MyLocationOverlay for users current position) and then use [ItemizedOverlay](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay.html)

If you need more functionality than this classes provide, you can implement your own `Overlay` by subclassing it.